# Placing Nodes Around a Circle

Tags: graphs, circles

I want to draw e.g. 9,13,17 nodes, evenly, around a circle in TikZ. How do I do this?

Then I also want to be able to edit easily the edges between the different nodes (to represent different graphs on those nodes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple approach using polar coordinates. Change the value of `\n` to adjust the number of circles. The nodes are named was `n-<number>`

[image: nodes around circle]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\pgfmathsetmacro\n{9}
\draw(0,0) circle (1);
\foreach \i in {0,...,\n} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\r{\i*(360/\n)}
    \node (n-\i) at (\r:1) {A};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

More complex example:

[image: complex circle]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw(0,0) circle (1);
\pgfmathsetmacro\n{6}
\foreach \i/\k in {0/A,1/B,2/C,3/X,4/Y,5/Z} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\r{\i*(360/\n)}
    \fill (\r:1) circle (1pt) coordinate (n-\i);
    \node at (\r:1.2) {\k};
}
\draw (n-0) -- (n-3);
\draw (n-0) -- (n-5);
\draw (n-0) -- (n-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: OK this is useful to me. But how do I get the nodes as actual black circles, rather than the letter A?

Comment: I have replaced the "A" with "$\circ$" or "$\bullet$" but that's obviously not the proper way.

Comment: @GinkgoBiloba: Instead of `\node ... {A};` try `\node [draw=black, inner sep=1pt] .. {};`, where the `inner sep` will control how big the circle is.

Comment: \node [fill=black, circle=1pt](n-\i) at (\r:1) {} seems to work but the nodes are too big

Comment: + How do I start adding edges between the nodes?

Comment: + How do I start labelling the nodes?

Comment: @GinkgoBiloba Try `\fill[black] (\r:1) coordinate (\n-\i);`. Then you can draw edges like `\draw (n-1) -- (n-4)`. And for labelling have a look at the extended for-syntax.

Comment: I currently have this:\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
\pgfmathsetmacro\n{13};
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\r{\i*(360/\n)}
    \node (n-\i) at (\r:1) (\i) {\i};
}
\draw [thick] (2) -- (1); 

\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: It draws a circle of numbers 1-13, and I can draw edges between them. The problem is how do I replace the numbers with actual nodes?

Comment: @GinkgoBiloba As I said, have a look at the extended for syntax with `\i/\k in {0/A, 1/N, 2/R}`. That's something you have to read about.

Comment: OK thanks but I'm not even sure what that is! If it's too difficult I may just settle for what I have now...

Comment: @GinkgoBiloba As I said, you have to read if you want to understand TikZ. I've appended a small sample of what I mean to my post.